# SQL Query to get number of entries

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select a random number of entries based on a specified parameter.

Like If I have a table T

```
T( id, data1, data2 ,no);
```

Now no is a field with a random bunch of numbers.

I want to get a random subset of T such that the number of no is at a particular value.

For example lets say I want total no=7

```
T(0,a,a,4);
T(1,B,B,4);
T(2,v,v,1);
T(3,d,d,2);
T(4,d,d,3);
```

The output of the query to the query would be either

```
T(0,a,a,4);
T(4,d,d,3);
```

OR

```
T(1,B,B,4);
T(2,v,v,1);
T(3,d,d,2);
```

etc.

Is this possible? I couldn't think of a logic. The best I could think of was retrieving them one row at a time and keep counting no but that's inefficient.

(NOTE: If the count exceeds no it is acceptable but not the other way around)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you pretty close.

```
create table t ( name varchar(1), num tinyint ) ;

insert into t (name, num) values ( 'a', 4 ), ('b', 2), ('c', 3),
    ('d',1), ('e', 4), ('f', 1),('g', 6);
```

Here's the query:

```
select * from 
  (select name, num, @cum := @cum + num as cumulate from 
    (select * from t order by rand()) as t3, 
  (select @cum := 0 ) as t1 
  ) as t2
where cumulate <= 7;
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a44dab/8). Im **sure** it can be optimized but I was curious to see how to create it.